# Failed to Scan query data by partition index after insert data using DML

Tags: ignite

I tried to query data by partition index, when I insert data using cache API, I can get data successfully, when I insert data using DML, I can't get data.

**I can get data using partition index using cache API**

```
IgniteCache cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache("cacheName");
cache.put(1, "v1");
ScanQuery sq = new ScanQuery(1); //1 is the id of partition used to store entry created above
cache.query(sq).getAll();
```

**I can't get data using partition index which is insert by DML**

```
IgniteCache cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache("tableName");
cache.query(new SqlFieldsQuery("CREATE TABLE tableName (id LONG PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR)")).getAll();
SqlFieldsQuery qry = new SqlFieldsQuery("INSERT INTO tableName (id, name) value (?，?)");
cache.query(qry.setArgs(11L, "Mary Major")).getAll();

ScanQuery sq = new ScanQuery(11); //11 is the id of partition used to store entry created above
cache.query(sq).getAll();         //nothing return here!
```

I tried SQL_PUBLIC_TABLENAME as cache name, I got Exception:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: SQL_PUBLIC_TABLENAME_7b146bba_cd7f_452f_8abc

**Q:**
How can I query data inserted by DML using partition index? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You do not need to call createCache explicitly because CREATE TABLE will also create a cache:
- `SQL_PUBLIC_TABLENAME` is the correct cache name. You can customize it by using [`CREATE TABLE (...) WITH "cache_name=PreferredNameForCache"`](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-reference/ddl)
- If you are going to have a single-column value of primitive type, you should use [`CREATE TABLE (...) WITH "wrap_value=false"`](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-reference/ddl). Then scan query will also work.

Comment: Thanks for replay, I can't set wrap_value to false because it has to be multi-column table, is there any other way to make scan query work, or in any way I can query data for specific partition?

Comment: You can do `cache.withKeepBinary().query(scanQuery)`.

Comment: It works, I need to deserialize binary object in this way, do you know what's the best practice of this?

Comment: You can just use fields from these objects. Alternatively, you can specify WITH "key_type / value_type" equal to same structure Java POJO classes and get rid of keepBinary.